# Removing the decimal part of a double without converting it to Int in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, ios11, computed-properties

Im a making a calculator App in ios and I have a computed property as shown below . I want to display for example let the display value be a whole number say 3.0 I want it to be displayed as just 3 and when the display value is not a whole number like this 3.4 then it should remain same . display.text is the label that is used to display the value of the calculator App
I have a code block like this :

```
 private var displayValue : Double {
            get {
               return Double(display.text!)!
            }
            set {
                display.text = String(newValue)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend `NumberFormatter`, this example creates a reusable formatter.

```
let decimalFormatter : NumberFormatter = {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    return formatter
}()
```

---

```
private var displayValue : Double {
    get {
        return Double(display.text!)!
    }
    set {
        display.text = decimalFormatter.string(for: newValue)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Man This is what I was looking for. :D

Comment: Or `decimalFormatter.string(for: newValue)` without the cast.

Comment: @MartinR Then I get *Cannot convert value of type 'Double' to expected argument type 'NSNumber'* (Swift 4.1)

Comment: It is `Formatter`’s method `string(for: Any)` instead of `NumberFormatter`‘s method `string(from: NSNumber)`. Swift 4.1 won’t make a difference as far as I know